# DynamoDB iOS Sample Permissions Error

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use the DynamoDB sample provided by AWS [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples), but I'm running into this error:

```
2014-12-17 11:26:32.374 DynamoDBSample[8952:766429] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:433 | __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke293 | Unable to refresh. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain error 0.)" UserInfo=0x7f8fdb82fd20 {Type=Sender, Message=Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, Code=AccessDenied, __text=(
"\n    ",
"\n    ",
"\n    ",
"\n  "
)}]
```

My IAM policy for both Auth and UnAuth is:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [{
    "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*",
        "dynamodb:*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ]
}]
}
```

I'm a little bit stuck on what to try next. Please help! Thank you

Comment: don't you just need to allow `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`? (from your trace)

Comment: Are you using the same role for auth and unauth? What is the trust relationship of the roles you are using?